# How to fix Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fd2e88c98c0>, "Cannot import name path"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build my first django server, and something is going wrong with getting the server running. 
 I try running: 
 `~/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/rssreader$ python manage.py runserver`
and it returns the following:

```
Performing system checks...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fd2e88c98c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 256, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/Coding Projects/rssReader/rssreader/rssreader/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.urls import path, include
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

rssreader/urls.py contains the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rss/', include('rss.urls'))
]
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, I'm totally new to django. Thanks!

Comment: which version of django did you install? Since you're running python 2.7, it cannot be 2.x. `path` was introduced in version 2.x. If you're new to Django, please install the latest python version (3.6 or 3.7) and use Django 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed a Django version that doesn't have `path` inside `django/urls/__init__.py`. If you used `pip` to install Django, check your version with `pip show django` and then run `pip install --upgrade Django`.

Otherwise, find a way to install a recent Django using your package installer (anaconda, apt, etc...)

Comment: When I run that command it says that I have version 1.11.20 and that's current.

Comment: @JonesCode Django's latest version is 2.2. `path()` is a 2.0 feature.

Comment: Is there a way to work around this using my current versions of django (1.11.2) and python (3.7)?

Comment: @JonesCode In this example, yes, since you don't use more advanced `path()` features. But it might not work in other files. Change line 2 to this: `from django.urls import url, include` and change `path('admin/')` to `url(r'^admin/')`, as well as `path('rss/')` to `url(r'^rss/')`